# Change default source directory for perl module Module::Build

Tags: perl, build, module, directory, default

I'm researching the perl module Module::Build in order to create a module. I need to know if there is a way to change the default directory for all *.pm files – lib/, to a custom directory. For example the source directory for *.pm files by default is “lib/directory”, I'd like to change it to “home//pm/” and copy from it instead.

**edit after daxim's comment:**

My directory structure is as goes:

```
home/user/workspace/try_ModuleBuild/LIBS/perl/Private/DB.pm
home/user/workspace/try_ModuleBuild/RELEASE/ModuleBuild/Build.PL
home/user/workspace/try_ModuleBuild/RELEASE/ModuleBuild/lib/API.pm
home/user/workspace/try_ModuleBuild/RELEASE/ModuleBuild/RESOURCES/prepare/form.html
```

All the files are empty.
My Build.PL contains:

```
my $self = Module::Build->new
    (
        module_name    =>   “Project”,
        dist_author    =>   [“My Name”],
        build_requires =>   {
                          'Test::More' => 0.98,
                                      'TAP::Harness' => 3.23
                    },
        dist_abstract       =>  “Example”,
        configure_requires  =>  { 'Module::Build' => 0.40 },
        requires        =>  {'perl' => '5.14.0'},
        add_to_cleanup          =>  [ 'Project::API-*' ],
        release_status      =>  'stable',
        use_tap_harness     =>  1,
        license         =>  'restrictive',
        RESOURCES_files => {'RESOURCES/prepare/form.html' =>'/RESOURCES/new/prepare/form.html'},

        lib_files=>{'/home/user/workspace/try_ModuleBuild/LIBS/perl/Private/DB.pm'=>'/lib/Private/DB.pm'},
        install_path           =>   {
                           'lib'=>'/home/user/MB/lib', 
                           'RESOURCES'=>"/home/user/MB/RESOURCES"
                                            },
);

    $self->add_build_element('RESOURCES');

    $self->add_build_element('lib');
    $self->create_build_script();
```

The problem lies with the file:

```
home/user/workspace/try_ModuleBuild/LIBS/perl/Private/DB.pm'
```

since its not in the directory:

```
home/user/workspace/try_ModuleBuild/RELEASE/ModuleBuild/LIBS
```

where the Build.PL is.

```
perl Build.PL
./Build manifest
./Build fakeinstall –install_base lib=/home/user/directory
```

fakeinstall returns result

```
“Installing /home/user/MB/lib/Private/DB.pm“
```

and runs without a problem.

After

```
./Build dist
```

however, DB.pm is missing from the created .tar.gz file.

Problem is I can only add files in the distribution from the home/user/workspace/try_ModuleBuild/RELEASE/ModuleBuild/ directory, while I want to add files from the home/user/workspace/try_ModuleBuild/LIBS/perl/ directory.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example which I can run? I have already spent 10 minutes trying to reconstruct the problem you're having, given the hints, but failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use Module::Build;
use File::Copy 'cp';

my $class = Module::Build->subclass(code => <<'');
sub process_EXTRALIB_files {
    my ($self, $target) = @_;
    while (my ($from, $to) = each %{ $self->{properties}{"${target}_files"} }) {
        cp $from, $to;
        $self->_add_to_manifest('MANIFEST', $to);
    }
}

my $self = Module::Build->new(
    ⋮
    RESOURCES_files    => {'RESOURCES/prepare/form.html' => 'RESOURCES/new/prepare/form.html'},
    EXTRALIB_files     => {'../../LIBS/perl/Private/DB.pm' => '../lib/Private/DB.pm'},
);
$self->add_build_element('RESOURCES');
$self->add_build_element('EXTRALIB');
$self->create_build_script;
```

---

```
perl Build.PL
./Build
./Build manifest
./Build dist
```

Comment: I figured the copying method myself, however I was trying to avoid pointless file duplication. Isn't there a way to just give a specific source directory to Module::Build?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't work for the `distdir` target. In any case, you need to manipulate the manifest because it only read the base directory downward.